# Various issues with the Stack Overflow for Teams "Familiar with the basics?" dialog

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-for-teams

New Stack Overflow for teams users (I'm not sure under what circumstances exactly) are shown the following dialog if they click the Stack Overflow logo in the bottom right of the page:

[image: Dialog with the following text: Stack Overflow for Teams We’ll reply as soon as we can Stack Overflow for Teams Familiar with the basics? Try some of the more advanced features to get even more out of Stack Overflow for Teams. Tags help you stay up to date with topics you’re interested in. Follow tags that are relevant to you, or add tags you think could be useful. Reactions are a great way to quickly engage with your teammate’s posts. From here, head to helpdesk to take a deeper dive on all things Stack Overflow!]

This has several issues:

- "with your teammate’s posts." should be "with your teammates' posts." (presumably you have more than one teammate)
- "head to helpdesk" should probably be "head to the Help Center" (it at *least* needs "the", and it should probably use the term used elsewhere for the Help Center)
- The alt text for the Stack Overflow logo is nonsense: "Jamie profile"
- "We’ll reply as soon as we can" doesn't make any sense (reply to what?)
- It's unclear what the reactions at the bottom are for.  You can click them and it remembers which one you last selected, but it doesn't appear to actually *do* anything, nor is there any explanatory text:
  [image: Clicking through thumbs-up, thumbs-down, and tada emoji. When clicked, the emoji go from grayscale to color and get larger, but nothing else happens.]

This isn't a great first impression of the amount of polish on the platform for a new user, so it'd probably be good to improve this.

Comment: What does that dialog have to do with stackoveflow, why would clicking a stackoverflow logo open that dialog rather than taking you to... stackoverflow,

Comment: @KevinB it's a button to show quick help and contact the Support team... in fact, putting the button there on the public Q&A might improve its visibility to new users, compared to the topbar...

Comment: I guess "Jamie" is another fictional support <s>person</s> bot's name...

Comment: I mean, sure, my point was more if it's not taking you to SO, and instead is a help hint, its icon should reflect that.

Comment: Re: "We’ll reply as soon as we can" is because if you go up one level that's actually part of the [Your conversations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOg3w.png) pane where you _could_ [send a message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s81PL.png). I do agree though, that the no-reply automated messages probably shouldn't have that text visible.